# GCC emits vastly different code using "-march=native" on similar architectures

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, sse, avx

I'm working on writing an OpenCL benchmark in C. Currently, it measures the fused multiply-accumulate performance of both a CL device, and the system's processor using C code. The results are then cross checked for accuracy.

I wrote the native code to take advantage of GCC's auto vectorizer, and it works. However, I've noticed that GCC has some odd behavior with the "-march=native" flag.

This is my loop:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE_SQRT 4096
#define SQUARE(n) (n * n)

#define ROUNDS_PER_ITERATION 48

static float* cpu_result_matrix(const float* a, const float* b, const float* c)
{
    float* res = aligned_alloc(16, SQUARE(BUFFER_SIZE_SQRT) * sizeof(float));

    const unsigned buff_size = SQUARE(BUFFER_SIZE_SQRT);
    const unsigned round_cnt = ROUNDS_PER_ITERATION;

    float lres;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < buff_size; i++)
    {
        lres = 0;
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < round_cnt; j++)
        {
            lres += a[i] * ((b[i] * c[i]) + b[i]);
            lres += b[i] * ((c[i] * a[i]) + c[i]);
            lres += c[i] * ((a[i] * b[i]) + a[i]);
        }

        res[i] = lres;
    }

    return res;
}
```

When I compile with "-march=native -Ofast" on a Broadwell system, I get nice vectorized AVX code.

```
.L19:
        vmovups ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rdx]
        mov     eax, 48
        vmovups ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rdx]
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm0, ymm5
        vmovups ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdx]
        vaddps  ymm4, ymm2, ymm5
        vmulps  ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vfmadd132ps     ymm4, ymm1, ymm0
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm3, ymm5
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm2, ymm0
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vfmadd132ps     ymm4, ymm0, ymm3
        vmovaps ymm1, ymm4
        vxorps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
```

Compiling with the same flags on a Piledriver system emits SSE2 instructions, but no AVX instructions, even though the architecture supports it. (I'll clarify my title here by saying that Broadwell and Piledriver are nothing alike, but they both support similar vector instruction set extensions, so the emitted code should be similar.)

```
.L19:
        mov     eax, 48
        movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rcx+rdx]
        movups  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [r13+0+rdx]
        movaps  xmm4, xmm0
        movaps  xmm1, xmm2
        movups  xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdx]
        addps   xmm4, xmm5
        addps   xmm1, xmm5
        mulps   xmm4, xmm2
        mulps   xmm1, xmm0
        mulps   xmm0, xmm2
        addps   xmm1, xmm4
        movaps  xmm4, xmm1
        mulps   xmm4, xmm3
        addps   xmm3, xmm5
        mulps   xmm0, xmm3
        addps   xmm4, xmm0
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        movaps  xmm1, xmm4
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
```

I can even compile the whole project with -march=broadwell, and run it on the Piledriver system, and it works, with a ~100% performance gain.

I'm compiling with GCC 5.1.0, and "-ftree-vectorizer-verbose" doesn't seem to work anymore, so the compiler's behavior is quite opaque. I haven't found any information about the flag being deprecated, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work anymore, and I'd really like to figure out what GCC is doing.

The whole project is here: https://github.com/jakogut/clperf/tree/v0.1

Comment: Did you try `-v` to see what `-march=native` expands to? See `-fopt-info-...` in the doc.

Comment: `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose` was replaced by `-fopt-info-vec-*`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AVX is disabled because the entire AMD Bulldozer family does not handle 256-bit AVX instructions efficiently. Internally, the execution units are only 128-bit wide. So 256-bit operations are split up thereby providing no benefit over 128-bit.

To add insult to injury, on Piledriver, there's a bug in the 256-bit store that reduces the throughput to [about 1 every 17 cycles](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

---

Your test case seems to be an anomaly. You don't have 256-bit stores in that critical loop - which avoids the bug. This (theoretically) leaves SSE on par with AVX for Piledriver.

The tie-breaker comes from the FMA3 instructions which Piledriver supports. This is probably why the AVX loop does become faster on Piledriver.

One thing you can try is `-mfma4` `-mtune=bdver2` and see what happens.

Comment: But I think due to the shared 128 bit units, the 256 bit ops can borrow the execution unit from the other core in the module, so it is more efficient in that case. I believe AMD even advertised that ("Flex FP")

Comment: It has two 128-bit pipes. So each cycle, it can handle either 2 x 128-bit instructions or 1 x 256-bit. The throughput is the same. By comparison, Intel processors since Sandy Bridge have had 2 x 256-bit pipes.

Comment: Having 2 instructions for the same performance is not good, as it takes up extra resources such as cache and registers (since you can't address the top half of a 256 bit register).

Comment: In his microarchitecture manual Anger writes "The throughput of 256-bit store instructions is less than half the throughput of 128-bit store instructions on Bulldozer and Piledriver. It is particularly bad on the Piledriver, which has a throughput of one 256-bit store per 17 - 20 clock cycles." So if I read that correctly, using 256-bit stores even on Bulldozer is still worse than two 128-bit stores. But he does not mention Steamroller so I guess on steamroller it's okay.

Comment: I think you mean `-mfma4` and not `-march=fma4`.

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution for GCC to use AVX but not do 256-bit stores by instead splitting the AVX register into high and low and do two 128-bit stores? (Maybe loads are a problem as well but then two 128-bit loads could be used to fill one AVX register).

Comment: @Zboson If I were to write it manually, I'd would use 128-bit instructions all the way. (including 128-bit FMA4) That's the most reliable way to avoid all the potholes. 256-bit has more problems than just the stores. reg-reg moves won't get rename-eliminated. Lane-crossing permutes are a mess from hell...

Comment: Those are good points and I would do the same thing I think but what about @Jester's in regards to this?

Comment: FYI, I have tested the mentioned stores, and indeed those are slow as hell. However, they can be easily emulated by two `vextractf128` instructions which work as fast as the normal 128 bit counterparts. I haven't  tried to come up with a test case that would show advantage of 256 bit version though.

Comment: @Jester I read somewhere that the only time that Agner Fog got 256-bit to be faster than 128-bit was when the code was limited by decoder bandwidth. That's unlikely to happen with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: GCC has options `-mavx256-split-unaligned-store` to split unaligned 256-bit stores into 128-bit `VMOVUPS` + `VEXTRACTF128`. Additionally, there is `-mprefer-avx128` to use AVX128 in auto-vectorizer.

Answer (score 6):

The output of "-march=native -Q --help=target" reveals that the AVX and AVX2 flags are not enabled by default on the Piledriver (bdver2) architecture.

Broadwell:

```
  -mavx                                 [enabled]
  -mavx2                                [enabled]
```

Piledriver:

```
  -mavx                                 [disabled]
  -mavx2                                [disabled]
```

Comment: Interestingly, debian gcc version 4.7.2-5 enables avx and does generated such code, although not vectorized (it's using mostly the `ss` variants).

Comment: PS: note that avx2 is disabled for a reason, since piledriver doesn't do avx2 :(

Comment: AVX is disabled because the entire Bulldozer family doesn't run AVX efficiently. (no faster than SSE) Furthermore, on Piledriver, there's a bug in the 256-bit store which makes AVX almost completely useless. Your case is an anomaly because you don't have 256-bit stores and the FMA3 probably becomes a plus.

Comment: @Mysticial that seems like an answer, that is very useful information, I dislike important information in comments because I have seen useful comments disappear and that helps no one in the long run.